# Using json_encode ( JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK ) with long floats in PHP

Tags: php, json, floating-point

I'm encoding a JSON file with the following function:

```
json_encode( $config, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_FORCE_OBJECT | 
JSON_PRESERVE_ZERO_FRACTION | JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK );
```

The issue is (or I'm pretty sure is) the *JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK* flag, is causing floats of 5 decimal places or more to be output like this:

```
1.0e-7
```

rather than this:

```
0.0000001
```

How can I keep my float values intact when outputting the file?

Very weird behavior as floats with shorter decimal places are being encoded just fine.

Comment: What's wrong with that? It's valid JSON and it represents the same value.

Comment: The software I'm generating the configuration file for is parsing the value as a string - I.E 1.07

Comment: That's a bug in the parser, it should follow the JSON specification. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19554972/json-standard-floating-point-numbers?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: This is why you shouldn't roll your own JSON formatter or parser, it's easy to miss some cases. Use an existing library.

Comment: It's not my software.

Comment: Well, it's wrong, and I don't think `json_encode()` has a workaround. I guess you could write a regular expression that looks for them and replaces it.

Comment: Aye I was hoping to avoid re-parsing the file to replace them with floating point values, but it looks like it's the only way.