# Writing numbers to JSON in scientific notation so that they don't get quotation marks around them

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, type-conversion, stringify

I have to store floating point numbers in JSON in scientific notation (just like the OP does in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19554972/json-standard-floating-point-numbers)).

The values I have to write into JSON are `<number>`s in my JavaScript (Angular/TypeScript) application, and I'm converting them into scientific form like `(42).toExponential()`.

The problem is that [toExponential()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toExponential) returns a string value, so later in my JSON notation `42` will become `"4.2e+1"` and not `4.2e+1`.

How could I get rid of the quotation marks?

Comment: with "Numbers" you don't get to "control" how they appear in JSON

Comment: So the only way would be to subsequently remove the quotation marks from the JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a replacer for the JSON.stringify function to convert all numbers to exponential, then use a regex to strip the quotes later, e.g.

```
const struct = { foo : 1000000000000000000000000, bar: 12345, baz : "hello", boop : 0.1, bad: "-.e-0"};

const replacer = (key, val) => {
  if (typeof val === 'number') {
    return val.toExponential();
  }
  return val;
}

let res = JSON.stringify(struct, replacer, 2)

res = res.replace(/"([-0-9.]+e[-+][0-9]+)"/g, (input, output) => {
  try {
    return isNaN(+output) ? input : output;
  } catch (err) {
    return input;
  }
})
```

gives:

```
{​​​​​
​​​​​  "foo": 1e+24,​​​​​
​​​​​  "bar": 1.2345e+4,​​​​​
​​​​​  "baz": "hello",​​​​​
​​​​​  "boop": 1e-1,​​​​​
​​​​​  "bad": "-.e-0"​​​​​
​​​​​}​​​​​
```

Comment: I would urge caution when using regular expressions or any naive string-replacement technique here; it is not hard for unexpected input to produce bizarre outputs.

Comment: e.g., input: `{"-.-e+0": 0.1}`, output: not JSON

Comment: @jcalz brings up a good point about regex, Rather than just replacing with "$1" I added a replacement function which tests if the output would be a number. Of course as with anything if it's being used in anger then some unit tests would be a good idea.